# Please introduce some distributed file system under windows server 2003

Tags: windows, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am doing load balancing under (windows 2003+tomcat 6), and it requires a shared folder which is exposed to each of the tomcat web application instances that may run on different host OSes. THere may be intensive I/O operations on the shared folder. So DFS, OpenAFS.....,any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider moving this question to [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com) since people over there have more knowledge of Servers and that kind of stuff.

Hope this helped